# Why aren't these strategy.exit() calls with stop losses getting triggered?

Tags: pine-script

I have 2 TPs and 2 SLs.

In each case one is based on ticks (`loss`,`profit`) and one is based on a price (`stop`,`limit`).

The TPs work more or less as intended...

**However, currently my `strategy.exit()` calls involving my stop losses never get triggered.**

I don't think there is any problem with the values; e.g. I've plotted `long_tp` to check it.

Particularly, note I set stop losses at the beginning, and then modify the `long_sl` variable (used in strategy.exit ID "EL-SL2") to the entry price once one TP has been reached.

Please see my script code (actual exit calls are at the very bottom):

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © ddctv

//@version=5
strategy("Double Top/Bottom + EMAs",overlay=true)


////////////
// Inputs //
////////////

max_bars_double_top_bottom = input(10)

take_longs  = input(true)

// Set TP1 and SL1 (based on ticks)
tp_ticks = input(3000)
sl_ticks = input(3000)

order_qty_contracts = input(2)



///////////////////
// TP & SL Logic //
///////////////////


// Quantity to exit on first TP to occur

exit_qty_pct = 50


// Initialize SL (to be based on nearest EMA below double bottom)

var long_sl = 0.0
plot(long_sl==0?na:long_sl,color=color.red)


// Initialize TP (based on inverse distance from nearest EMA below double bottom)

var float long_tp_ema = na


// Set TP2 (needs help)

// if strategy.position_size>0 and strategy.position_size[1]==0
//     long_tp_ema := strategy.position_avg_price + (low[1]-ema800)
plot(long_tp_ema==0?na:long_tp_ema,color=color.green)


// Move SL to entry after 1 TP is taken, and update exit_qty_pct to 100

if (strategy.position_size>0 and strategy.position_size[1]>strategy.position_size) // or (strategy.position_size<0 and strategy.position_size[1]<strategy.position_size)
    long_sl := strategy.position_avg_price
    exit_qty_pct := 100


// Reset equity_qty_pct to 50 after position is flat

if strategy.position_size==0
    exit_qty_pct := 50



//////////
// EMAs //
//////////


ema50  = ta.ema(close,50)
ema200 = ta.ema(close,200)
ema800 = ta.ema(close,800)

plot(ema50,"EMA 50",color=color.aqua,linewidth=1,transp=25)
plot(ema200,"EMA 200",color=color.gray,linewidth=2,transp=25)
plot(ema800,"EMA 800",color=color.purple,linewidth=3,transp=25)



/////////////////////////////////////
// W / Double-bottom Pattern Setup //
/////////////////////////////////////
//
// (Meant for use with Renko bricks, but ideally should also work for regular bars)


// Define simple double bottom pattern

double_bottom = ta.lowest(close,1)[1]==ta.lowest(close,max_bars_double_top_bottom)[2] and close>open
plotshape(double_bottom,style=shape.triangleup,location=location.belowbar,size=size.tiny)


// Check trending for entry condition

// Is the 50 EMA falling and are the 200 & 800 EMAs falling?
mismatch_w = double_bottom and ema50<ema50[1] and (ema200>ema200[1] or ema800>ema800[1])
plotshape(mismatch_w,location=location.belowbar,size=size.normal)



/////////////
// ENTRIES //
/////////////


// LONGS

if mismatch_w and take_longs and (low[1]>ema200 or low[1]>ema800) and strategy.position_size==0
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long,qty=order_qty_contracts)
    
    // Set SL2 according to position of setup in relation to EMAs (200 or 800)
    if low[1]>ema200 and low[1]>ema800
        long_sl := math.max(ema200,ema800)
    else if low[1]>ema200 and low[1]<ema800
        long_sl := ema200
    else if low[1]<ema200 and low[1]>ema800
        long_sl := ema800
    
    long_tp_ema := close + (low[1]-long_sl)




///////////
// EXITS //
///////////

strategy.exit("EL-TP1", from_entry="Long", profit=tp_ticks, qty_percent=exit_qty_pct)
strategy.exit("EL-TP2", from_entry="Long", limit=long_tp_ema, qty_percent=exit_qty_pct)
strategy.exit("EL-SL1", from_entry="Long", loss=sl_ticks)
strategy.exit("EL-SL2", from_entry="Long", stop=long_sl)
```

Does anyone know why my last two exits (the stop losses) never get triggered?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your complete chart and mark where you expect your SL to get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine SL & TP in single `strategy.exit` call:

```
strategy.exit("EL-TP1", from_entry="Long", profit=tp_ticks, loss=sl_ticks, qty_percent=exit_qty_pct)
strategy.exit("EL-TP2", from_entry="Long", limit=long_tp_ema, stop=long_sl, qty_percent=exit_qty_pct)
```

Comment: Hi @AndreyD ! The reason I haven't done this is because I take 50% profit first, then once position is reduced I take 100% on second exit. However there is no means of setting independent quantities for profit and loss with an exit call. Also once one is triggered it will not work again from my understanding.

Comment: each `strategy.exit` "guards" it's own part of entry (partially or full, depends from `qty_percent`) and other `strategy.exit` can "guards" remaining part of entry. Your two last `strategy.exit` guards only remaining part of qty (100-exit_qty_pct)%.